# Is there a viable Nortel 64-bit VPN client?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, nortel

Looking for a Nortel VPN client that will run on 64-bit Win7.

Comment: download Nortel vpn client from here
http://vpnclient.conseco.com/install.htm

Answer (score 1):

If the Nortel device is speaking ipsec, the [Secure Entry client](http://www.ncp-e.com/en/solutions/vpn-products/secure-entry-client.html) from NCP will likely work.  It's a bit pricey at nearly $150/license, but it has indeed connected to every ipsec vpn that I have tried it against; including Juniper, Cisco, and Netgear.  I did need the assistance of the VPN concentrator admin for setting some of them up though.

Answer (score 0):

Agree about NCP.  I don't think any vendor (Cisco, Juniper) are making 64bit IPSEC clients.  They are trying to push people to SSL.  You can also try the [Shrew VPN Client](http://www.shrew.net) which is free.  They don't explicitly say they support Nortel, but it's worth a try.  They seem to support everything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get anything else to work you can try LogmeIn Hamachi (the un-managed version of course), which may work for you since it runs on 64-bit windows (as a 32-bit app).